# Python can't find my folder windows path, but don't know why

Tags: python, python-2.7, openapi

I'm trying to install my openapi2jsonschema to point out at an yaml file and create a json file, but when i do a

`C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test>openapi2jsonschema --strict openapi-3.2HF3.yaml`

i receive the next error, but i don't know why?

```
Downloading schema
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 1505, in open_local_file
    stats = os.stat(localfile)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: ''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\openapi2jsonschema.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openapi2jsonschema\command.py", line 63, in default
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 1483, in file_open
    return self.open_local_file(req)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 1522, in open_local_file
    raise URLError(exp)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: ''>
```

I tried to read documentations, different responses from the web but i don't find anything usefull..

Comment: According to [this comment](https://github.com/instrumenta/openapi2jsonschema/issues/19#issuecomment-453855204) in the `openapi2jsonschema` repository, "to use local file you must use file protocol: file:///AbsolutePath". Can you try this and see if this resolves the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The traceback you encountered suggests that there was a problem opening a local file using Python's `urllib.request` module. The error occurred at line 1505 of the `request.py` file within the `urllib` module.

To troubleshoot this issue, consider the following steps:

1. **Check File Existence**: Ensure that the file specified by the `localfile` variable exists in the specified location. Verify that the file path is correct and that the file is accessible from the Python script.
2. **File Permissions**: Check if the file has the appropriate read permissions for the Python script. Make sure the script has the necessary permissions to access the file.
3. **File Path**: Verify that the file path does not contain special characters or non-ASCII characters that could cause issues. Ensure that the file path is in the correct format and does not contain any unexpected characters.
4. **File Encoding**: If the file contains non-ASCII characters or uses a non-standard encoding, it might lead to problems when attempting to open the file. Make sure the file is encoded correctly and matches the encoding expected by the Python script.
5. **Python Version Compatibility**: Ensure that the version of Python you are using is compatible with the `urllib.request` module and the rest of your code. Some incompatibilities or changes between Python versions could lead to errors.

If the issue persists, consider providing more context and code snippets surrounding the part of your script where you are using `urllib.request`, as well as the specific error message received. This additional information will help the community diagnose the problem more accurately and provide targeted solutions.